# How can I use a variable in the field of m2m?

Tags: python, django

First I am extracting the model name of the M2M field from the value I get through the loop. Then I am trying to add data to m2m table, but this `AttributeError: 'ProductAttributes' object has no attribute 'm2m_model'` is coming.

```
attribute  = ProductAttributes.objects.get(pk=pk)
for key in common_keys:
    if initial[key] != new_data[key]:
        # Getting m2m model in lower case
        m2m_model = apps.get_model(app_label=app, model_name=key)._meta.model_name
        attribute.m2m_model.add(new_data[key])
```

Here's the problem `attribute.m2m_model.add(new_data[key])`
If I directly name the field then it works fine like below:
`attribute.color.add(new_data[key])`
`attribute.ram.add(new_data[key])`
I want to make it dynamic.

**Here is my model:**

```
class ProductAttributes(models.Model):   
    color               = models.ManyToManyField('Color')
    band_color          = models.ManyToManyField('BandColor')
    ram                 = models.ManyToManyField('RAM')
    vram                = models.ManyToManyField('VRAM')
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`getattr(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), but it looks like bad code design to rely that the field is the model name in lowercase:

```
attribute = ProductAttributes.objects.get(pk=pk)
m2m_model = apps.get_model(app_label=app, model_name=key)._meta.model_name
for key in common_keys:
    if initial[key] != new_data[key]:
        # Getting m2m model in lower case
        getattr(attribute, m2m_model).add(new_data[key])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I get an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment`. Here we get the name of the model with the key of the loop that is assigned above the loop.